# Sql client throwing error 1045 but I can get in through command line?

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, ubuntu

I have a linux VPS that I can connect to fine using command line.

```
root@vps27625:~# mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 4604
Server version: 5.5.38-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

but if I use any sql client it's throwing error 1045 access denied for user root (using password: YES)

What could be the possible reasons for this happening?

Comment: It deppends from what do you permit. If you forbid root to connect remotely, you will have access denied. What about using another mysql account? Btw, it is not good practice to use root for remote connections.

Comment: I used a different user and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you use root remotely. Most installs of mysql denied that by default. So use other user instead.

Actually using root account to remote login is not good practice.

Answer (score 0):

the remote login for root on your mysql server is disabled. You can set this using

**> mysql_secure_installation**

command to enable or disable it.

Comment: Using root for remote login is not good practice. That's why it is DISABLED by default